# Can I run Hadoop streaming applications without setting up HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-streaming

Can I run a Hadoop streaming application without setting up HDFS?  I'd like to test a Hadoop streaming application on my local machine.  In particular I'm trying to follow the instructions for [this tutorial](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/) but, instead of specifying a path on the DFS for inputs/outputs I'd like to specify a local path.

The help page for the hadoop-streaming.jar states that the `-input/-output` values are on the DFS.  Am I missing an option somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Streaming scripts read from the stdin and write to the stdout. The below scripts can be used to make the streaming scripts read from a local file system. Note that it doesn't work in a distributed fashion and is mainly used for unit testing of the scripts.

> cat ./input.txt | ./word_count_map.py | sort -k1,1 | ./word_cound_reduce.py > output.txt